# Rails: Completed 500 Internal Server Error, with AngularJS $http.post call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently working on this tutorial: [AngularJS Tutorial: Learn to Build Modern Web Apps with Angular and Rails](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails/#wiring-everything-up)

In the tutorial project, users can create Blog **Posts** and **Comments** for those **Posts**. So far I've been able to create Blog **Posts** (which are saved into database), but when I try to create a **Comment** for a **Post**, then I get the following **error**:

```
Started POST "/posts/16/comments.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-15 08:32:40 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"body"=>"6", "author"=>"user", "post_id"=>"16", "comment"=>{"body"=>"6"}}
Comments create action entered... 6
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

NameError (undefined local variable or method `post' for #<CommentsController:0xb6036e50>):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

**Note: line** *“Comments create action entered... 6
”* is `logger.info` message.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
        logger.info "Comments create action entered... " + params[:body]

    comment = post.comments.create(comment_params)

    respond_with post, comment
  end

  def upvote
    comment = post.comments.find(params[:id])
    comment.increment!(:upvotes)

    respond_with post, comment
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    respond_with Post.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with Post.create(post_params)
  end

  def show
       logger.info "show action entered... " + params[:id]

    #respond_with Post.find(params[:id])
    #the code below works,  the line above resulted in error: 406 (Not Acceptable)
    render json: Post.find(params[:id]).to_json 
  end

  def upvote
    post = Post.find(params[:id])
    post.increment!(:upvotes)

    respond_with post
  end

  private

  def post_params
    logger.info "post_params entered..."
    params.require(:post).permit(:link, :title)
  end
end
```

In the `PostsController`'s `show` action, I had previously changed line: `respond_with Post.find(params[:id])` to: `render json: Post.find(params[:id]).to_json` because line: `respond_with Post.find(params[:id])` produced error: `GET http://0.0.0.0:3000/posts/4 406 (Not Acceptable)`

I'm not sure, but the above issue might be related to *internal error (500)* message, why post is not found. Also if I use line: `respond_with Post.find(params[:id])` in the `PostsController` then I still end up with the same problem with the **Comment** creation.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  respond_to :json

  def angular
    render 'layouts/application'
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
FlapperNews::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'application#angular'

  resources :posts, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
    resources :comments, only: [:show, :create] do
      member do
        put '/upvote' => 'comments#upvote'
      end
    end

    member do
      put '/upvote' => 'posts#upvote'
    end
  end
end
```

Below is **post.js** file that does the Ajax calls in which the `o.addComment` function's `$http.post` call tries to create the Comment in the following way: `$http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments.json', comment);`

```
angular.module('flapperNews').factory('posts', ['$http',
    function($http){
       var o = {
            posts: []
        };

     o.getAll = function() {
            return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
                angular.copy(data, o.posts);
            });
        };
        o.create = function(post) {
            console.log("o.create");
            return $http.post('/posts.json', post).success(function(data){
                o.posts.push(data);
            });
        };
        o.upvote = function(post) {
          return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/upvote.json')
            .success(function(data){
              post.upvotes += 1;
            });
        };
        o.get = function(id) {
          return $http.get('/posts/' + id).then(function(res){
            return res.data;
          });
        };
        o.addComment = function(id, comment) {
            console.log("addComment " + id + ", comments " + comment )
          return $http.post('/posts/' + id + '/comments.json', comment);
        };
        o.upvoteComment = function(post, comment) {
            console.log("o.upvoteComment " + post.id + ", comments " +comment.id)
          return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id + '/comments/'+ comment.id + '/upvote.json')
            .success(function(data){
              comment.upvotes += 1;
            });
        };
        return o; 
    }
]);
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.config([
  '$stateProvider',
  '$urlRouterProvider',
  function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        resolve: {
          postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
            return posts.getAll();
          }]
        }
      })
      .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        resolve: {
          post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
            console.log( "$stateParams.id " +$stateParams.id)
            return posts.get($stateParams.id);
          }]
        }

      })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
}]);
```

My rails version is 4.0.2

Any help would be appreciated, because I've been struggling with the code for a couple of hours :-) Anyway, I'm glad that there is Stackoverflow forum where one can ask some advice :-)

Comment: it seems in your `comments_controller`, `post` is undefined. Try add `post = Post.find(params[:id])` before you call `post`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this has nothing to do with angular. You don't have the post defined, so add:

```
post = Post.find params[:post_id]
```

also, i think your comment belongs_to post, you should set the post as the comment's post before saving the comment, so:

```
@comment.post = post
```

Comment: Excellent, I'm finally able to save Comments into database.  Thanks :-)